# Will the behavior "Committing entries from previous terms" of raft cause unexpected result?

Tags: raft

In raft's paper, there is a situation described by the figure.
[image]

the entry2 may be commited after server1 restart.

my question is:

If entry2 is requested by mistake, the request of client failed because of the failed of server1. Thus, the client may think that the mistaken behavior is not applied by state machine which in fact do after the restart of server1 like figure(e).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Raft, and any other transactional system based on unreliable communication, there is always the possibility that a client's request may return an "undefined" result if the network fails at just the wrong time.

This problem is inherent; see [Two Generals' Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem).

Here "undefined" means that the client does not know whether or not the transaction was actually committed. The only way to tell is to open a new transaction and look and see.

In software this is often reported as a "retryable" exception.

A practical way to deal with this is to (a) always retry transactions when getting a retryable exception, and (b) ensure client transactions are always idempotent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my opinion, it is very hard to ensure the client transactions are always idempotent (some op like increase 1) and it is almost impossible for client to see the previous op is success (because it did not know the origin value before increase 1). I think it is better not to make any change when server1 crash which seem to be impossible now. After all thanks a lot, it clarify some of my  misunderstanding.

Comment: There is no way for the client / server to know that.
Consider the chain of events, (1) client send request, (2) server commits it, (3) network issues prevent the server from letting the client know.

As far as the client is concerned, this failed, but the server is operating normally. For that matter, it is very easy for the problem to not even be _observable_ by the server.

Comment: A more practical way is to give a transaction id for every request in client.